# Flutter android deep links is not working

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking, firebase-hosting, android-deep-link

I am currently implementing the deep linking feature. I have followed [Flutter official documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-app-links) but it is not working for me. Here is my assetlinks.json file which is hosted on Firebase

```
[{
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.myname.appname",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
      ["sha256_from_google_app_signing_cert"]
    }
  }]
```

and here is my Android manifest file

```
 <!-- deep linking -->
            <!-- <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" /> -->
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="app.mydomain.online" />

            </intent-filter>
```

flutter_deeplinking_enabled is commented because it is mentioned in the documentation as I am using the [applinks](https://pub.dev/packages/app_links) package.

and here is my firebase.json file

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "appAssociation": "NONE"
}
```

I tried to access the file through a browser and it worked but I am not sure what I have done wrong so the app is not being opened automatically.

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```html
[{
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.myname.appname",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
      ["sha256_from_google_app_signing_cert"]
    }
  }]
```

This should be hosted on -> yourdomainname.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Not on firebase

Comment: it is hosted on my domain using Firebase Hosting. Is this wrong?

Comment: is this file assetlinks.json accessible ?

Comment: yes I can access it through via browser